# Not able to convert from Array data to CLLocationCoordinate2D in swift to draw a Polyline in mapview

Tags: arrays, iphone, swift, mkpolyline, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have array (`coordinatesArray`) of data which has double values like following.

```
(
    "-61.4149691",
    "42.9572076"
)
(
    "-61.4126004",
    "42.9572026"
)
(
    "-61.476674304",
    "42.9572032"
)
```

This is mapData

```
 (
        "-61.4149691",
        "42.9572076"
 )
```

So, I took a loop for converting each index data as latitude and longitude by converting as double.

```
 if let coordinatesArray = geoMetrys.value(forKey: "coordinates") as? NSArray {
    for mapData in coordinatesArray {
     print(mapData)

  let latitude = (mapData[0] as NSString).doubleValue
  let longitude = (mapData[1] as NSString).doubleValue

  var coordinatesToAppend: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = [latitude, longitude]

  var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinatesToAppend!, count: coordinatesArray.count)
 mapView.add(polyline)
```

But, its showing error while compiling time.

> ```
> `Type 'Any' has no subscript members` for following lines
> ```

```
  let latitude = (mapData[0] as NSString).doubleValue
  let longitude = (mapData[1] as NSString).doubleValue
```

I have an array in that I have data of value as latitude and longitude.
So, I am trying to draw a polyline in mapview with these values.

Can anyone suggest me where I am failing to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the line

```
if let coordinatesArray = geoMetrys.value(forKey: "coordinates") as? NSArray
```

returns an array of type `Any` (i.e. `[Any]`). After that, when you use the for loop

```
for mapData in coordinatesArray
```

you are essentially looping over an array of `Any` where, in every iteration, an item (of type `Any`) is assigned to `mapData`. Now if this `mapData` is an array itself, you have to explicitly specify it as

```
if let dataArray = mapData as? NSArray {
    let latitude = (dataArray[0] as NSString).doubleValue
    let longitude = (dataArray[1] as NSString).doubleValue
}
```

Comment: Yes, but its showing Contextual type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' cannot be used with array literal for                                             var coordinatesToAppend: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = [latitude, longitude]

Comment: That's an error in your next line. This solution fixes your first problem. Your second problem is the way you are assigning the values to `latitude` and `longitude`. `CLLocationCoordinate2D` does not take an array. Instead you would have to do something like `let coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)`

Comment: I am getting following error on runtime Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x109a7b208) to 'NSString' (0x108bec0d0).
in this line                                             let latitude = (dataArray[0] as! NSString).doubleValue

Comment: Seems like `dataArray[0]` is not an `NSString` after all. Instead it seems that it is an `NSNumber`. Try changing it for both `dataArray[0]` and `dataArray[1]`. Or just change it to `"\(dataArray[0])".doubleValue`